# typescript giving error in navigation.navigate

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Hi I'm trying TS in react native for first time and I am getting errors from typescript when I try to use `navigation.navigate()` function.
This is my Navigator.tsx

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator, NativeStackScreenProps } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import HomeScreen from "../Screens/HomeScreen";
import SecondScreen from "../Screens/SecondScreen";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import PhoneEntry from "../Screens/Auth/PhoneEntry";
import PhoneVerification from "../Screens/Auth/PhoneVerification";
import { CountryListDataProps } from "../components/CountryCodeModal";
import { FirebaseAuthTypes } from "@react-native-firebase/auth";
import ConfirmationResult = FirebaseAuthTypes;

export type RootStackParamList = {
  "Home": undefined;
  "Login": undefined;
  "PhoneEntry":undefined;
  "PhoneVerification":{phoneNumber:string, selectedCountry:Partial<CountryListDataProps>,verification:ConfirmationResult}
};

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

const CustomStackNavigator = () => {
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isLoggedIn);

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={"Home"} screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={auth?SecondScreen:HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="PhoneEntry" component={PhoneEntry}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={SecondScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="PhoneVerification" component={PhoneVerification} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
export type PhoneVerificationType = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList,"PhoneVerification">
export type PhoneEntryType = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList,"PhoneEntry">
export type HomeType = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList,"Home">

export default CustomStackNavigator;
```

In my PhoneVerification.tsx I have my component like this:

```
function PhoneVerification({navigation,route}:PhoneVerificationType)
```

similarly in other components as well. However when I try to use `navigation.navigate("PhoneVerification",{myPropsHere})` in any screen. Typescript is showing error

> Argument type "PhoneVerification" is not assignable to parameter type
> any
>
> Argument type {selectedCountry: CountryListDataProps, phoneNumber:
> string, verification: ConfirmationResult} is not assignable to
> parameter type any

I've checked other solutions on stackoverflow, but nothing worked for me.

Comment: do you have comma here `("PhoneVerification" {myPropsHere})` or you made a typo when you posted the question?

Comment: @Yilmaz yes, I do. its just a typing mistake here